# Cannot select database during wordpress local setup

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, web-development-server

I have installed wordpress and I am trying to connect database. I am seeing this error:

```
Cannot select database
The database server could be connected to (which means your username and password is okay) but the database could not be selected.

Are you sure it exists?
Does the user root have permission to use the database?
On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_. Could that be the problem?
If you do not know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.
```

I have checked that Database name, username and database host are correct but still I am not able to solve the error. I have tried using 127.0.0.1 but still no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to be given permissions to access the database.

Comment: I checked and root is given access.

Comment: does the root have a password ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).